# amsthm in clean

Tags: spacing, theorems, cleanthesis

I am looking for a good latex template for my phd. I did not like the classicthesis because of the huge margin and the collapsed table of contents.
I found the cleanthesis to be just what I was looking for (http://cleanthesis.der-ric.de/) but unfortunately I have problems with the package amsthm.

If I use it like that

```
\begin{lemma}
This is my Lemma
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
Thats my proof
\end{proof}
```

than I get a huge gap between my lemma and the according proof.

Anyone a Idea how I can prevent the gap?

Comment: Provide your own template. This is normally the best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This document style introduces vertically spacing between paragraphs, thus giving too much space before proofs, and uneven spacing around theorems, etc.  Redefining the internal commands of `amsthm`, putting negative space into `\topsep` of the proof environment, and making theorems start with with a `\parskip` and end with no spacing gives the following result with reasonably uniform spacing:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, twoside=true, openright, parskip=full, chapterprefix=true, 11pt, headings=normal, bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc, titlepage=on, captions=tableabove, draft=false]{scrreprt}%

\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep-6pt
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\def\th@plain{\thm@preskip\parskip\thm@postskip0pt\itshape}
\def\th@definition{\thm@preskip\parskip\thm@postskip0pt\normalfont}
\def\th@remark{\thm@headfont{\itshape}\normalfont\thm@preskip\parskip\thm@postskip0pt}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[chapter]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[lemma]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[lemma]

\newcommand{\thesisTitle}{The Clean Thesis Style}
\newcommand{\thesisName}{Ricardo Langner}
\newcommand{\thesisSubject}{Documentation}
\newcommand{\thesisDate}{February 1, 2012}
\newcommand{\thesisVersion}{0.2}

\newcommand{\thesisFirstReviewer}{Jane Doe}
\newcommand{\thesisFirstReviewerUniversity}{\protect{Clean Thesis Style University}}
\newcommand{\thesisFirstReviewerDepartment}{Department of Clean Thesis Style}

\newcommand{\thesisSecondReviewer}{John Doe}
\newcommand{\thesisSecondReviewerUniversity}{\protect{Clean Thesis Style University}}
\newcommand{\thesisSecondReviewerDepartment}{Department of Clean Thesis Style}

\newcommand{\thesisFirstSupervisor}{Jane Doe}
\newcommand{\thesisSecondSupervisor}{John Smith}

\newcommand{\thesisUniversity}{\protect{Clean Thesis Style University}}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityDepartment}{Department of Clean Thesis Style}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityInstitute}{Institut for Clean Thesis Dev}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityGroup}{Clean Thesis Group (CTG)}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityCity}{City}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityStreetAddress}{Street address}
\newcommand{\thesisUniversityPostalCode}{Postal Code}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[figuresep=colon,sansserif=false,hangfigurecaption=false,
hangsection=true,hangsubsection=true,colorize=full,colortheme=bluemagenta]{cleanthesis}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}          % arabic page numbering
\setcounter{page}{1}            % set page counter
\pagestyle{maincontentstyle}    % fancy header and footer

\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\begin{lemma}
  A lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{proof}
  The proof.
\end{proof}
A line of text across the page to demonstrate some spacing effects of
the spacing changes.
\begin{lemma}
  Another lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{definition}
  A definition.
\end{definition}
\begin{remark}
  \blindtext
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow - Thank you very much! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

In your post you are not mentioning the name of your university so for a moment I will assume that you are getting your PhD somewhere in U.S. (about 50% of all annually awarded PhD in mathematics on the world are awarded in U.S. so that is a damn good guess).

Any R1 ties PhD granting department in U.S. would have mandatory LaTeX template. Typically template is based on some University wide requirements (read reverse engineering of some ugly Microsoft Word document that somebody from Provost office created). The LaTeX template can be obtained by going to your graduate secretary. The situation is probably similar at R2. A tier R3 schools probably award so few PhDs that they would be happy with anything.

Just as a remark for people who might be getting PhD at the department other than mathematics or physics perhaps I would go with that ugly Word document because the last thing you want to do before defending thesis is converting  your dissertation from TeX to Word.

Comment: I'm from germany and we dont use word in the math department. But thanks anyway :).